# info.plist icon: No light from above

Tags: iphone, ipad, info.plist

What do I add to my info.plist so that the device does not add a light from above rendering on top of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the icon effect, see the screenshot (**UIPrerenderdIcon** is the raw key name):

[image]
[image]